# Perl eval EXPR enclosed by sinlge or double quotes

Tags: perl, eval, double-quotes, single-quotes

I can see the following from `perldoc -f eval`:

```
   eval EXPR
   eval BLOCK
   eval    In the first form, the return value of EXPR is parsed and 
           executed as if it were a little Perl program.
```

And I've seen EXPR is enclosed by single or double quotes, for example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $operator ( qw?+ - *? )
{
        my $sum = eval "3 $operator 2";
        print "$sum\n";
}
```

I have a question for the quotes: `"3 $operator 2"` is `EXPR` in thic case, the return value of this `EXPR` is `"3 + 2"` for the first iteration, according to the perldoc, `"3 + 2"` is parsed and executed, but it is a double-quoted string literal, how can Perl get the result of `5` eventually? I mean, when `EXPR` is enclosed by single or double quotes, are the quotes part of `EXPR` or just delimiters? If changing it to single quotes, the program would crash, so it seems that quotes have the same meaning as in single-quoted or double-quoted string literals.

Thanks

Comment: Nice pick for `qw` delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are not part of the eval syntax.  EXPR means any expression, whether a quoted string, a variable, a function call, the result of some operation, or anything else.

Changing to single quotes shouldn't make the program crash, but would not interpolate your variable, producing code that won't eval successfully, making eval return undef and set an error message in $@.

Comment: I'm still confused. Expression is `"3 $operator 2"`, which is a double-quoted string. `eval` should 1) evaluate the string first and then 2) evaluate the return value. Whichever stage `$operator` gets interpolated by `+`, the result is another double-quoted string `"3 + 2"`. How Perl continue evaluating such a double-quoted string to `5`? It is a string with 5 characters, not an arithmetic expression.

Comment: as its a double quoted string Perl will first interpolate the variables so your string becomes `3 + 5`, this is the return value of expression which is then given to eval.  The eval will then parse this to make sure its valid perl syntax which is. The eval is then executing the syntax and quite correctly produces 5 as the result. You keep refering to it as a string, but thats not how eval sees it. as the eval doc says eval executes the return value as a little perl program. Think of eval doing it as `perl -e '3 + 5'`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, I mean the return value is `"3 + 2"` (a double-quoted string), not `3 + 2` (an arithmetic expression). Is that right?

Comment: its not passing it as a single or double quoted string. as i said its just giving `3 + 2` to the eval. no quotes at all. then eval parses it as perl code then executes it as perl code.

Answer (score 1):

### `eval("3 $operator 2")`

The string literal (i.e. the Perl code) `"3 $operator 2"` produces the string `3 + 2`, which is passed to `eval` to be evaluated as Perl code. This results in the number five being returned by `eval`.

### `eval('3 $operator 2')`

The string literal (i.e. the Perl code) `'3 $operator 2'` produces the string `3 $operator 2`, which is passed to `eval` to be evaluated as Perl code. This isn't valid Perl code, so `eval` returns undef and sets `$@` to `Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "2 $operator"...`

Answer (score 0):

add next code after you `eval`:

```
print $@   if $@
```

This will show to you what is wrong.

In your example

- when you use double quotes the `3+2` is evaluated
- when you use single quotes the `3 $operator 2` is evaluated

if you add code I advice you will see error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "2 $operator"
    (Missing operator before  $operator?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "$operator 3"
    (Missing operator before 3?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "2 $operator "
```